# The method showFullScreen(Activity) in the type AppFlood is not applicable for the arguments (new Handler(){}} error

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried to implement appflood ads and get error. I really don't know why i get this error:

```
The method showFullScreen(Activity) in the type AppFlood is not applicable for the arguments (new Handler(){} .
```

My MainActivity:

```
protected Handler handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case SHOW_ADS: {

                // Display the AppFlood Ad
                AppFlood.showFullScreen(this);
                Gdx.app.log("Show Ads", "");

                break;
            }

            case LOAD_ADS: {
```

I will get error in manifest too. The error is Element type "meta-dataandroid:name" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". But i have it.

This is my manifest:

```
<activity
android:name="com.appflood.AFSplashScreenActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.appflood.mraid.MraidBrowserActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.appflood.AFFullScreenActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>
<receiver
android:name="com.appflood.AFReferralReceiver"
android:exported="true" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"

 />
```

Comment: Replace `this` by `YourActivit.this`

Comment: Now application stopped working. But it solved the error.